# Three easy pieces

Tags: riddle, wordplay, tribond

> 1. Cram. No Crete lust.
> 2. She. Who Kyle? Till.
> 3. Out! I'm dinner elder.

Find three objects beginning with an E, each described by one line, given they are clued similarly.

Hint:

> a) Each object has three pieces.
>  b) The three triplets have spatial order in common.
>  c) The three clues are arranged similarly.

Comment: Congratulations on passing 30k, Tom, fully deserved. I've no idea how to solve this one but it looks enticing.

Comment: Why are all puzzlers so enigmatic?

Comment: I like how the title says "easy" and then everyone's stumped for weeks :P

Comment: Is that tribond tag completely accurate @Tom ?

Comment: @Brandon_J - I think so. The 'three pieces' of the title applies to the objects and these share a common property. I'll expand the hint. Thank you for the bountification!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I've got the answers

1. Cram. No Crete lust.

   > This is an anagram of **Crust, Mantle, Core** so the answer is **Earth**
2. She. Who Kyle? Till.

   > This is an anagram of **Shell, White, Yolk** so the answer is **Egg**
3. Out! I'm dinner elder.

   > This is an anagram of **Outer, Middle, Inner** so the answer is **Ear**

Hints

> Each answer is associated to a triplet with the general spatial ordering of outside, middle, inside. Each clue is arranged as an anagram. Also, as pointed out by jafe in the comments, the letters of each outer part are on the outside of the clue, this makes finding the anagram a bit easier.

Comment: Rot13[Nyfb, gur yrggref bs rnpu bhgre cneg ner ba gur bhgfvqr bs gur pyhr rgp.] Very nice!